# Three.js OrbitControls.js zoom scaling not linear

Tags: javascript, three.js

First of all this is the library I'm talking about:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js
My problem is the following:
I can't figure out where the zoom is exactly defined. It scales to the distance between camera and an original point, but I can't seem to find it.
I already know that it can't be line 31-33 or getZoomScale()-function (line 276) and many others as well(for the different events).
Has anyone worked with it yet and has a guess where the definition is?
Or how to scale the zoom to a set value instead of that what it is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A camera ([PerspectiveCamera](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera)) is used in 3D development to let you define the distance, angle, field of view etc. This results in a 2D representation of the scene which consists of lights, meshes, sprites etc. when rendered. It has a position and a rotation stored in 3D vectors, matrices or quaternion.

Controls ([Orbit Control example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit), [misc_controls_orbit.html](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html)) move around the camera by mapping user events like mouse wheel/move to a new position and rotation. In case of an orbit control you can think of a camera as being bound to a thread that forces it to always look at a center point when moved. Given a certain radius the camera moves around on a sphere.

In line 74 of the orbit sample the camera is passed to the OrbitControl, in line 16 of OrbitControls.js you see that this.object is the camera passed to it following the variables/properties that can be set to restrict/enable things. In line 81 (this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;) you see that the **camera has a zoom** and the value is saved by the control for reset purposes. The update function contains the code that repositions the camera depending on the input (mouse, touch, pointer). (Line 156, 159 spherical.radius)

You can set the camera to an initial position and rotation (camera.lookat):

```
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);        
    camera.position.x = 0.1;
    camera.position.y = 3.5;
    camera.position.z = 6;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

The GitHub Wiki link (just for reference): [Home](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki)

Comment: Thanks for the quick refresher. The zoom of the camera-object is a constant (by default 1), always. I will look into the rest of it where that sphere is applied. Thanks

Comment: True it's 1, but you can set it to 10 for example.. but not sure if you have to explicitely call controls.update(); after that. Also you could simply position the camera further away or closer. I updated my answer.